# Consequences of withholding information for a UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas

I want to go to UK in December 2015 for tourism for two weeks.
But while I was checking the application in part 5.9  it asks "Have you ever worked for any organisation ..." and I ticked yes in the Armed forces section
which I have completed this year in September 2015. Besides doing my national service I am working full time as a doctor. I work as a Doctor in a private hospital and I got my salary from it and I've sorted my bank statement and payslips.

The problem is my army certificate shows only the date of my service
nothing else, so will the ECO be suspicious and think "how come he is serving in the armed forces and in the same time working as a doctor?" I only have a letter from the hospital proving that I'm working there.

Comment: Please don't use an ALL-CAPS title, it is annoying and distracting.

Comment: What is the information that you are withholding?

Comment: no i am just wondering whether they will question how i am serving in army at the same time as working full time

Comment: Most people in armies work. Quite a few armies have full time medical staff out of the ranks. Always be honest, being caught on a lie can have serious concequenses.

Comment: Put "yes" and where further details are requested note, e.g. "national service", and how many hours/week or days/year this took up.

Answer (score 4):

In the situation you have described, there's a relevant decision from the Tribunal which was handed down in 2010.  The Tribunal determined that non-disclosure was the same thing as lying. Part of the determination says...

> “When a direct question is asked, and answered untruthfully, there is
>   both a false representation and a non-disclosure; and it is not open
>   to an Appellant who gives an untruthful answer to a direct question in
>   an application form to say that the matter was not material.”

Source: Tribunal [Kenya [2010] UKUT 165 (IAC)](https://tribunalsdecisions.service.gov.uk/utiac/37669)

We observe from Section 5.9 of the application that it is a direct question...

[image]

What that means is you should answer the questions on the form.  If you think the ECO will get confused, you can add a clarifying explanation.  If you don't answer the questions (or withhold information) and you get caught, then they can exercise Paragraph 320 to ban you.

Somewhat related (deception by silence at a UK port): [Reapply for Visa or Take Chance at Border?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41806/reapply-for-visa-or-take-chance-at-border)

Comment: okay I understand that if i withhold information i will be at risk of getting myself banned. however i am very confused as to what else i can do. I served in army in a location away from home and away from my place of work. but i am getting paid from my workplace while i am in army. does that make any sense?. i dont know what to put in the application. its very confusing.

Comment: Which part of "yes or no" is confusing?

Comment: @user35891, your situation is not particularly unusual or odd. Many people in the UK are full-time employed and are also 'military reservists' for the British armed forces: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_reserve_force#United_Kingdom Just explain the facts clearly and truthfully.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, UK visa forms allow you to put extra information on a separate piece of paper. So I would suggest doing that to explain the situation exactly. Hope this helps.. our visa policy is a bloody mess, good luck!